# Save to/read from file (.dat) in a subfolder in C

Tags: c, file, save, subdirectory

I am basically trying to write to/read from file in a subfolder in C. The folder in question is located at `C:/users/me/Test/`.
An example of my feeble attempts can be found below.
`<dirent.h>` have been included.

```
    DIR *dirPS = opendir("/me/Test/");

    int m1[2][2] = {{7,2},{4,3}};

    FILE *fout = fopen("m1.dat", "wb");
    fwrite(m1, sizeof(m1), 1, fout);
    fclose(fout);
```

All files end up under `me` and not under `me/Test`.
Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All files end up under me and not under me/Test.

Looks like you are running your program with the current directory at "C:/users/me".

You can use:

```
FILE *fout = fopen("Test/m1.dat", "wb");
```

to create the files under "C:/users/me/Test".

You don't to use `opendir()` for this use case. It doesn't help in any way.

Before you do that, make sure the directory exists and you have permission to create files in it.

Answer (score 0):

The `opendir()` function does not change the working directory.  It simply gives you a handle by which you can examine the directory entries.  You could instead use `chdir()`, but it might be better simply to specify the full path when you open the file:

```
FILE *fout = fopen("/me/Test/m1.dat", "wb");
```

That might still trip you up if the current working directory is on a different drive, but otherwise it shiould work.

Comment: @userjuicer, I can't test your actual code in your actual environment, but I am pretty confident in saying that it is not the `fopen()` call I specified to you that causes that error.  In fact, my closest possible rendition of it for my environment compiles fine and runs without error.  Run yours in a debugger to find out where your error really occurs.